# codeigniter localhost setup 404 page not found error

Tags: codeigniter, localhost

I have a localhost setup(i use apache's virtualhost setup) for a site I am working on with codeigniter. I use SVN for the site.

I decided to change the localhost-domain name and the root-folder name(this is the folder from within which I check out SVN) to which the localhost-domain points.

To show a better picture, I changed;

```
sledge-vicky.localhost  to  hammer-vicky.localhost
```

Changed the document-root's name from "sledge" to "hammer". Have changed the document root,directory paths in the virtualhost setup too;

```
<VirtualHost hammer-vicky.localhost>
 DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\vicky\projects\hammer
 ServerName hammer-vicky.localhost

 <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\vicky\projects\hammer">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Have set the domain-name in windows' hosts file. Have set/changed the base-url and database settings in config.php and database.php too(I use environment dir; **_environment/vicky/config.php, _environment/vicky/database.php** ).

In the code where we switch to the required app-environment, I have set the code to switch to my app-environment too.

**http://sledge-vicky.localhost/** was working fine. 
After the local-domain name and root-folder name change, accessing **http://hammer-vicky.localhost/**  throws a '404 page not found error'.

Any idea what could be wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

My bad debugging. I got it working. I had to change other settings in some files specific to my environment (in my case, /application/config/_environment/...) that were related to some global settings(which in my case, others sharing the same svn-repository had changed).